# Удалить несколько символов в txt-файле

Tags: php

У меня есть текстовый документ с большим количеством строк.
Мне нужно удалить все из этого документа, но из каждой строки оставить только icon.xxxx_xxxx_xxx. Подскажите, каким образом можно так сделать?

Пример одной строки:

```
0   1   1   1   7   15  0   LineageWeapons.small_sword_m00_wp           LineageWeaponsTex.small_sword_t00_wp                0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   icon.weapon_small_sword_i00                 -1  1600    8   0   5F006E  0       1       27  1   1   LineageWeapons.small_sword_m00_wp       1       1   LineageWeaponsTex.small_sword_t00_wp                4   ItemSound.sword_small_1 ItemSound.sword_big_7   ItemSound.sword_mid_6   ItemSound.public_sword_shing_4  ItemSound.itemdrop_sword    ItemSound.itemequip_sword       10  8   6   1   0   8   0   0   0   0   379 0   1   1   1000    0   -1  0           0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  1.00000000  1.00000000                      LineageWeapons.rangesample      0.94999999  0.55000001  0.55000001  11.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000                          -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удаления данных можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями. Если размер файла не очень велик, можно извлечь все его содержимое при помощи функции `file_get_contents()`, извлечь нужные данные в массив и записать в файле объединенный в строку массив нужных значений при помощи функции `file_put_contents()`

```
<?php
$filename = 'index.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$pattern = '/icon\.[^\s]+/';
preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $out);
file_put_contents($filename, implode(PHP_EOL, $out[0]));
```

Или, если файл велик, можно открыть временный, переписать туда построчно очищенное содержимое первого файла, а после закрытия обоих файлов скопировать новый файл на место старого

```
<?php
$filename = 'index.txt';
$filetemp = tempnam('/tmp', 'temp');
$fd = fopen($filename, 'r+');
$ft = fopen($filetemp, 'w+');
$pattern = '/icon\.[^\s]+/';
if($fd && $ft) {
  while (($line = fgets($fd, 4096)) !== false) {
    if(preg_match($pattern, $line, $out)) {
      fwrite($ft, $out[0].PHP_EOL);
    }
  }
  fclose($fd);
  fclose($ft);
  copy($filetemp, $filename);
}
```

Comment: Первый код помог, но не много не то, что нужно. Код отбирает все icons - а в строке их может быть несколько.  Как сделать, чтобы код удалял все только до 1 упоминания icons в строке ну и все остальное что после?

Comment: @Елизавета попробуйте второй вариант, он описывает нужное вам поведение.

Comment: Благодарю Вас!!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) и модификатором `m` -

> Модификатор *m* указывает на то, что текст, по которому ведется поиск, должен рассматриваться как состоящий из нескольких строк. По умолчанию механизм регулярных выражений рассматривает текст как одну строку вне зависимости от того, чем она является на самом деле. Соответственно метасимволы '^' и '$' указывают на начало и конец всего текста. Если же этот модификатор указан, то они будут указывать соответственно на начало и конец каждой строки текста.

```
<?php
$filename = 'index.txt';
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$content = preg_replace('%^.*?(icon\.[^\s]+).*+$%m', '$1', $content);
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Регулярное выражение `%^.*?(icon\.[^\s]+).*+$%m` захватывает целиком каждую строку, в которой есть искомая подстрока `icon.xxxx_xxxx_xxx` (группа захвата `(icon\.[^\s]+)`). При этом в группу захвата попадает только первая подстрока, так как до нее используется ленивый перебор символов `.*?`. И соответственно функция preg_replace() меняет захваченную строку на группу захвата `$1`.